# Table format issues. Column lines and horizontal lines are not with proper margins + caption alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions, columns

Table format issues. Column lines and horizontal lines are not with proper margins. Caption alignment is also not proper if change in minipage width setting

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{table}

\centering

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}

\hline


\textbf{Id} & \textbf{Age} & \textbf{Lab-tests} & \textbf{Time-in-Hospital} \\ \hline


1  & 45 & 13 & 35 \\ \hline

2  & 35 & 7 & 20 \\ \hline

3  & 30 & 5 & 25 \\ \hline

4  & 55 & 10 & 28 \\ \hline

5 & 40 & 14 & 38 \\ \hline

\end{tabular}

\caption{\label{tab:ptabular} Patients}

\end{minipage}

\end{table}

%%%%%
```

Output:

[image]

If I put in `minipage`:

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
```

I get the following output:

[image]

Now, I could not understand why the caption is not center aligned. Why are columns not appearing and horizontal lines are extended?

I would like to mention that I am not using `\documentclass{article}` (if use it, it works perfectly), but a specific documentclass of paper that is, `\documentclass{kais}`. KAIS style file is available here.
http://www.ucs.louisiana.edu/~xxw8007/kais/LaTeX/

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I've tested with the `kais.cls`  and have no problem. Could you post a full compilable code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Why are you using a minipage to enclose the `tabular` environment?

Comment: If you put an \fbox around the minipage, you will see that the tabular doesn't fit.  OTOH, my result didn't look anything like yours, probably due to unknown packages or all those blank lines.

Comment: @JohnKormylo
I create a sample. Result still the same.
\documentclass{kais}
\begin{document}
\section{New Section}
\label{sec:new}
In the methods, abc \dots abc xyz \dots 
\begin{table}
\small
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
{Id} & {Age} & {Lab-tests} & {Time-in-Hospital} \\ \hline

1  & 45 & 13 & 35 \\ \hline
2  & 35 & 7 & 20 \\ \hline
3  & 30 & 5 & 25 \\ \hline
4  & 55 & 10 & 28 \\ \hline
5 & 40 & 14 & 38 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{\label{tab:ptabular} Patients}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}

Comment: @Bernard


\documentclass{kais}

\begin{document}

\section{New Section}
\label{sec:new}
In the methods, abc \dots abc xyz \dots 

\begin{table}
\small
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline


{Id} & {Age} & {Lab-tests} & {Time-in-Hospital} \\ \hline

1  & 45 & 13 & 35 \\ \hline
2  & 35 & 7 & 20 \\ \hline
3  & 30 & 5 & 25 \\ \hline
4  & 55 & 10 & 28 \\ \hline
5 & 40 & 14 & 38 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{\label{tab:ptabular} Patients}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}

Comment: @leandriis

I have a requirement to put to tables side by side. I will put another table with \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth} if the issue of  horizontal lines and columns get resolved

Comment: It seems that loading `array` solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, despite the warnings on ‘caption not aware ofthe document class’:

```
\documentclass{kais}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{floatrow, caption}

\begin{document} 

\section{New Section} \label{sec:new}

In the methods, abc \dots abc xyz \dots

\begin{table}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\centering
\small
 \begin{floatrow}
  \ttabbox[\FBwidth]{
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 {Id} & {Age} & {Lab-tests} & {Time-in-Hospital} \\
 \hline
  1 & 45 & 13 & 35 \\
   \hline
   2 & 35 & 7 & 20 \\
  \hline
  3 & 30 & 5 & 25 \\
   \hline
   4 & 55 & 10 & 28 \\
   \hline
   5 & 40 & 14 & 38 \\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}}
  {\caption{\label{tab:ptabular} Patients}}
  \ttabbox[\FBwidth]{
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 {Id} & {Age} & {Lab-tests} & {Time-in-Hospital} \\
\hline
  1 & 45 & 13 & 35 \\
   \hline
   2 & 35 & 7 & 20 \\
  \hline
  3 & 30 & 5 & 25 \\
   \hline
   4 & 55 & 10 & 28 \\
   \hline
   5 & 40 & 14 & 38 \\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}}
  {\caption{\label{tab:ptabular-a} Patients}}
   \end{floatrow}
   \end{table}

   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It work in sample document. 

But it does't work in my actual document. When i add \usepackage{array} , it gives me error : ! Missing # inserted in alignment preamble.
<to be read again>
\cr
l.85
There should be exactly one # between &'s, when an
\halign or \valign is being set up.

Comment: @Berbard, Nevertheless i appreciate your time and effort. I think my issue is not resolvable. Following is the list of all packages that i use in my document. 
\usepackage{wrapfig,epsf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref,url}
\usepackage[sort,numbers]{natbib}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

Comment: @Faaiz: Could you post a small (complete) document reproducing the problem? I'll add that using the lines from `booktabs`  or those from `hhline` or  from `boldlines ` also work. Not sure it's related, but `epsf` is obsolete  (`\includegraphics`  does the job) and `hyperref` should be the last  loaded package, with very few exceptions;